# Relative Positioning in CSS

Tags: css

```
.loading-icon {
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
  line-height: 25px;
```

In firefox and chrome, the object is centered in the page, whereas on IE10 the object is not centered and appears towards the left

Comment: please provide jsfiddle...

Comment: not sure what that means to be honest

Comment: i mean example here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sr55s/
The inline-block statement also makes stuff weird. Change it to block and it will work. Or remove it because it is block by default.

Comment: It is working fine for me in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 margin attributes. Chrome and Firefox handle it one way and IE handles it another.

Delete the duplicate and change the first to:

```
margin: 50px auto;
```

Also as mentioned in the comments, change   `display: inline-block;` to

`display: block;` or just delete it.

Comment: The second setting will over-rule the first, but it is sensible to remove one of them.

Comment: @AndyG that's exactly what's happening, hence the OPs issue (well, one of the issues)